# Can't access website in virtualbox after Windows 10 update

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu, virtualbox

Host: Windows 10 (updated)
Guess: Ubuntu 14.04.5 
Virtualbox: 5.2.12 r122591 (Qt5.6.2)

After the windows update I tried to access my virtual machine and it kept giving me random errors. After of dozens of tutorials and guides my current settings are:

> Hosts file (on windows): 192.168.56.2 devserver
>   /etc/network/interfaces file(on ubuntu)(couldn't paste):
>
> ```
> auto eth1
> iface eth1 inet static
> address 192.168.56.2
> netmask 255.255.255.0
> broadcast 192.168.56.0
>
> auto eth0
> iface eth0 inet dhcp
>
> auto eth2
> iface eth2 inet dhcp
> ```
>
> Virtualbox network:
>
> ```
> Attacked to: Host-only Adapter
> Name: VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter #3
> Adapter Type: PCnet-FAST III (am79C973)
> Promiscuous Mode: Allow All
> MAC Address: 0800275A1DBB
> ```

But I still can't connect to the website. It keeps giving me the "page not found" message.

Comment: Try installing a brand-new virtual machine with all defaults, see if that works. If it does, then something happened to your old machine definition. You could probably make a new machine definition and just attach the old machine's drive image. Unless it is a problem in the guest configuration. But that would give you an idea where the problem is.

Comment: I reinstalled but all the settings stayed the same. Nothing changed.

Comment: Did I do something wrong in the post? I'm getting downvotes.

Comment: This isn't a programming question so isn't on-topic here. It would be better on [su], or possibly [ubuntu.se]

Answer (score 0):

**[Solution](https://superuser.com/questions/1327964/cant-access-my-websites-inside-virtualbox-after-the-last-windows-10-update)**

/etc/network/interfaces file

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 192.168.56.2
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    broadcast 192.168.56.0
```

hosts file

```
192.168.56.2 devserver
```